# PhpStorm: add break-line after <p> in reformat code

Tags: phpstorm, settings, automated-refactoring

I am using PhpStorm and I am configuring the auto reformatting setting to my likings.

But I got in to a problem. When I reformat it automatically does a break-line before the `</p>`, and that is good. Now the problem is that it does not add an break-line after `<p>` and I like this to happen.

Here is an example:

Before refactor:

```
<p>A lot of text is placed here and when there is a lot of text.
It will go to the next line</p>
```

After refactor:

```
<p>A lot of text is placed here and when there is a lot of text.
    It will go to the next line
</p>
```

What I want after refactor:

```
<p>
    A lot of text is placed here and when there is a lot of text.
    It will go to the next line
</p>
```

**Question:** What settings do I need to change to have the outcome that I want when I use the auto refactoring in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently possible, please vote for [WEB-310](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-310) to be notified on any progress with this feature